# $f,g \in C^\infty$ agree on a n-hood, yet are different?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, differential-geometry, smooth-functions

Can $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions that agree on a neighborhood, yet are not equal everywhere ?

Comment: Consider $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x > 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \leq 0$, and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=0$ for every $x$.

Comment: Well, that solves my issue ! You can write it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Yes, the identity theorem really does rely on analyticity (is that a word? :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @TheSilverDoe, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=e^{−1/x^2}$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq0$, and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=0$ agree on $\mathbb{R}_{\leq0}$. Yet aren't equal on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: This idea is used to create [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).